# Mysql FULLTEXT MATCH - do i need a new index if I'm searching a subset of columns?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm using Mysql 5.6.

Lets say I have a `users` table with `id, name, address1, address2`.  I want to do a FULLTEXT search on `name, address1, address2`, so I put a combined fulltext index on those columns, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD FULLTEXT (name, address1, address2);
```

Normally, if I search users, i want to search all three of these fields, so I do this, which only returns results with a score higher than zero, and orders them by highest score first:

```
SELECT id, MATCH (name, address1, address2) 
AGAINST ('my search term') as score 
FROM users 
WHERE MATCH (name, address1, address2) 
AGAINST ('my search term') > 0 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Let's assume that's all working fine. 
Later, I decide that I just want to search the `address1` and `address2` fields, and ignore `name`.  So, I do this:

```
SELECT id, MATCH (address1, address2) 
AGAINST ('my search term') as score 
FROM users 
WHERE MATCH (address1, address2) 
AGAINST ('my search term') > 0 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Do i need to add a new, separate FULLTEXT index on `address1, address2` in order to do this?

Similarly, if I want to just search `name`, do I need to add another FULLTEXT index just on `name`?

In other words, is the rule that every time you do this `MATCH (col1, col2, col3)`  there needs to exist an index on that specific set of columns?

Does it make any difference what order the columns are in?

thanks!

Comment: Yes for the second query you are ideally going to need a other index..

Comment: MySQL optimizer should be smart enough to see `MATCH (address2, name, address1)` (for example)  can also use the index  `(name, address1, address2)` atleast it can and does with BTREE indexes so iam pretty sure it can do the same with FULLTEXT indexes you can verify using [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: I just did an experiment and it seems happy with reordering.  And yes, it looks like you do need an index for each subset.  I maybe should have just done the experiment in the first place, it was much quicker than writing this question.  thanks

Comment: No problem.. With a BTREE index you can "cheat" more or less a bit imagine if you would have `INDEX(name, address1, address2)` and you want to search on `address1` and `address2` you could write `WHERE name <> '' AND address1 = '<value>' AND address2 = '<value>'` .. But it will not be a effective index lookup it will be a full index scan at least it will most likely will be better then a full table scan.. The effective index would be offcource `INDEX(address1, address2)`

Comment: The order of columns doesn't matter (AFAIK), the set does. In theory you could use a redundat condition `MATCH (name, address1, address2) AGAINST ('my search term') AND MATCH (address1, address2) AGAINST ('my search term')`. The engine would use the index for the first condition and then check the second condition without the index on the filtered result set. In theory! But MySQL doesn't permit the second condition without a corresponding index - Though it should be able to. However you could work around it with a word boundary RLIKE.